# Bash: Zero-pad a number with a variable for the digit count

Tags: bash, sequence, string-formatting

I need to zero-pad a sequence of numbers in a loop in Bash. I know how to do it with

```
seq -f "%03g" 5
```

or the comparable `printf` approach, also

```
for index in {003..006}
```

The problem I did *not* find an answer to is that I need the number of digits to be a variable:

```
read CNT
seq -f "%0$CNTd" 3 6
```

Will return an error

```
seq: das Format »%0“ endet mit %
```

I have not found any way to insert a variable in a format string or any other way to produce a zero-padded sequence where the number of digits comes from a (user-provided) variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A variable name (`CNT`) should be enclosed in curly braces when it is followed by a character (`d`) which is not to be interpreted as part of its name,
2. `seq` doesn't support `%d`, you should use `%g`.

```
$ read -r CNT
$ seq -f "%0${CNT}g" 3 6
00003
00004
00005
00006
```

Comment: 2. was a mis-copying, in the original example at the top of my question I had it correct.  
1. I *did* try the curly braces - however, for some reason I only put them *around* the `$CNT` ...

Comment: The indices are of course also variables, but *they* didn't cause any problems to me. `seq -f "%0${CNT}g" $FROM $TO` works.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `seq`, but did you know the `*` operator in `printf`?

```
printf "%0*d\n" ${CNT} 5
```

Comment: No, I didn't. This is useful information too, but indeed I think the `seq` solution is more natural to the use case in question.

Comment: @uli_1973 ... but `seq` is an external tool, while `printf` is a Bash built-in.

Comment: @BenjaminW. good point, but not relevant since I only need that for personal use.

Comment: @uli_1973 Sure, but answers here are not just for whoever asked them, but for everybody who finds them later when encountering a similar problem, so ideally they employ universal best practices.

Comment: So what _is_ the * parameter to printf?  An answer should include an explanation, not an unanswered question.

Comment: The question was `Zero-pad a number with a variable for the digit count`. I could have written: The `*` is an operator that you can use for defining zero padding with a variable, but I thought that was obvious. Sorry.